# How to reference event handlers that are not in code-behind, but are in another object?

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I can set the DataContext to any object, then have the properties of that object binded to my controls.

I want to do the same thing with event handlers. I have a class of event handlers that I want the xaml to use. However, the xaml looks for event handlers in the code behind.

```
    <Button Click="OnSearch"/>
```

I get warnings that tells me that OnSearch does not exist in the code behind class.

1. I want OnSearch to be in another object. How can I do that?
2. What if I want the xaml to look for the event handler in the data context object?

I'm new to WPF and I'm trying to learn. I tried Binding on the event handlers but that obviously did not work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think for this purpose yuo should use **Commands** and not **Events**.

You need define **YourRoutedEvent** that derives from [RoutedCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routeduicommand.aspx)

And bind it to the command of your **Button** control. In your **YourRoutedEvent** you can implement whatever complex logic you want to behave in different way during different states of your application, which is what you want probabbly, that's why asking about dynamic event binding.

Here is a sample link that dimonstrates command binding technique:

[Command binding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/morgan/archive/2010/06/24/simplifying-commands-in-mvvm-and-wpf.aspx)

Regards.

Comment: Thanks I read up on Commands. Never knew they existed until now!